# Android RTL support is affected by the flavor's resConfigs

Tags: android, gradle, register-transfer-level

Following some recent changes to one of our flavor regarding supported languages, we noticed it somehow also affects the RLT support.

```
flavorA {
    resConfigs 'en', 'pt', 'fr', 'es', 'de'
}

flavorB {
    resConfigs 'en'
}
```

With the configuration, when the device language is Arabic or any other RTL language:

- `A` content is **locked** Left To Right (LTR)
- `B` content is Right To Left (RTL)

Now if I am updating `flavorA` to `resConfigs 'en'`. It now supports RTL again

Looking at the documentation for `resConfigs`, I am not seeing anything about affecting RTL capacities:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support#specify-the-languages-your-app-supports

How can I get RTL to be supported by `A`?